# Website deleted from server, no back-up

Tags: linux, wordpress

I hope i am in the right forum now. Couldn't find a stackexchange forum closer to my problem than this one.

Anyway i have a server running Direct Admin. Somehow a Wordpress installation on one of my domains has been deleted. Both the code as the database are completely wiped clean.

By backup only gets stored for 7 days and i didn't notice it till after a month.
Google hadn't cached the website yet and neither did wayback machine.

The problem is that i performed several researches and posted the results and so on the blog of my Wordpress installation. Now i really need those results and i can't find a way to bring them back.

I've asked my hosting company if they could do anything for me, they can't help.
Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Have you tried the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/)?

Answer (score 4):

**No** - there is no way to recover your website or your database is not backed up with your hosting provider (or as in your case, the nightly backups don't have it).

**Long Answer**

Your host will likely need to do forensic data analysis of their hard drives in order to stand any chance of getting anything at all, and due to the insanely high cost and specialist nature of that kind of operation (it costs tens of thousands of dollars, requires them to totally dismantle/replace disks), you will need to be an extremely important customer or have very deep pockets for them to even consider this.

Your only option at this stage is to ask your hosting provider if they keep any backups greater than 30 days old for archive purposes (if their stated archive time is 7 days, I very much doubt it, but it's worth asking).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have no alternatives. Try to check your site database, it can be alive (or your provider may back it up. Most of theme do this periodically).